# Сколько процессов можно запускать на сервере? python threading

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Пишу парсер, в цикле перебираю ссылки и отправляю запросы, хочу каждый запрос отправлять в новый процесс, если будет 500 ссылок, потянет ли какой-либо сервер все процессы? (linux)

Comment: Скорее всего да, если хватит памяти. Но появляется вопрос, зачем каждую ссылку обрабатывать в отдельном процессе. Все 500 запросов в асинхронном режиме может отправить практически одновременно и получить ответы один процесс и при этом он потратит в десятки раз меньше ресурсов чем 500 процессов и даже затратит на это меньше времени. Другой вопрос сколько процессора надо, что бы разобрать полученные результаты. Вот тут, если не хватает процессора есть смысл выделять несколько процессов (не больше, чем есть ядер процессора) для разбора

Comment: Ну вот смотрите, у меня вот такой код

    for i in items_list:
        process = Thread(target=testparse, args=(i['url'], i['uid'], i['price'], i['product_name'], i['cityName']))
        process.start()
        c += 1
        time.sleep(1)

Как мне один процесс запустить в цикле?

Comment: Тут вы запускаете потоки. Вопрос только зачем ? Вы понимаете что запуск одного потока требует раз в 5 больше ресурсов чем обработка одной ссылки. А запуск процесса - раз в 10. Кроме того, если потоков или процессов у вас больше чем ядер, то начинаются постоянные переключения контекстов, которые то же очень медленные. Потоки/процессы начинают конкурировать. Если вы запустите потоков/процессов скажем в 2 раза больше, чем у вас ядер, то итоговая работа будет выполнена за время в полтора раза большее, чем если бы потоков было меньше

Comment: А так то запуск происходит примерно так же как потоки, только с использованием multiprocessing.Process. Но настоятельно рекомендуется запускать процессов не больше чем ядер и отдавать им работу из главного процесса по мере необходимости с использованием очередей (Queue). И самое главное, если у вас 90% времени уходит на ожидание ответа из сети (а так оно и происходит когда вы тянете какие то ссылки с веба) то и это все не нужно. Нужно использовать aiohttp для параллельного получения ответов с нескольких ссылок в одном единственном потоке

Comment: aiohttp я пробовал, тогда вылетает капча на сервере из-за большого кол-во запросов.

Когда я запускаю процесс в цикле, то обработка 1 ссылки занимает 2 секунды, и потом закрывается как я понимаю, как мне это лучше реализовать?

Comment: А вот если я запущу не Thread,а multiprocess? будет разница?

Comment: так 500 процессов тем более приведут к капче, Значит вам надо наоборот делать меньше запросов. Для начала узнать сколько запросов в параллель проходят без капчи, И выдавать запросы с задержкой,  тем же aiohttp. Делать либо простую задержку, вроде asyncio.sleep(). Либо например отдавать N запросов с небольшой задержкой между ними, а следующие запросы подавать по мере завершения предыдущих, так что бы одновременно не более N работало

Comment: А можно с вами в тг связаться? тут не совсем удобно описывать код итд

Comment: Я сейчас проверил, если запускать multiprocessing, то cpu до 100% нагружается!, а вот с threading вообще не загружается процессор